# pyspark get the row immediately after the one selected

Tags: python, pyspark, data-analysis

i have a dataframe (df) like this:

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| One | Two | x |
| One | Two | full |
| One | Two | y |
| One | Two | z |
| One | Two | full |
| One | Two | u |
| One | Two | e |

Using PySPark i want to mark the element/rows immediately after col3=="full" with 1 otherwise 0, like this:

| col1 | col2 | col3 | flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| One | Two | x | 0 |
| One | Two | full | 0 |
| One | Two | y | 1 |
| One | Two | z | 0 |
| One | Two | full | 0 |
| One | Two | u | 1 |
| One | Two | e | 0 |

At the moment this is my idea, but i'm not taking the row immediately after...:

```
df.withColumn('flag',f.when(f.col('CD_OPERAZIONE')=='full',1).otherwise(0))
```

can you help me?

Comment: What do you mean "Immediately after" your question is not clear at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use lag and when statement

```
w= Window.partitionBy('col1','col2').orderBy('col1')
df.withColumn('x', when(lag('col3').over(w)=='full',1).otherwise(0)).show()

+----+----+----+---+
|col1|col2|col3|  x|
+----+----+----+---+
| One| Two|   x|  0|
| One| Two|full|  0|
| One| Two|   y|  1|
| One| Two|   z|  0|
| One| Two|full|  0|
| One| Two|   u|  1|
| One| Two|   e|  0|
+----+----+----+---+
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: assign row number to each row using row_number function
Step 2: filter the dataframe with col3==full, now you have the row numbers where col3 is full, call it dataframe2 lets say
step 3: create a new column adding one to the row number column in dataframe2, now you will have row numbers of the immediate row next to the ones having col3 as full
step 4: join dataframe one with dataframe2 via inner join after selecting the new column from dataframe2 on row_number from dataframe1 and new row number column on dataframe2.

Pardon for no code, on my mobile. Let me know if you want help still.